# window location href not working when submit is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

In some of my programs the window.location.assign works and goes to a different page. But I have been trying a mixture of window.location.href and window.location.assign on this page and one other, and neither seem to work. I am unsure why, I don't really understand why it is not working as I tried copying it the same from my other page. It just refreshes the page instead of going to a different one. This is a register form, and it stores the data in a database and that all works perfectly, it's function is fine it just won't go to a different page. I am using chrome browser.

Comment: `onSubmit=return false` should be `onSubmit="return false"`, although I'm not sure if that's the only problem.

Comment: oh my i didnt realize it was not in brackets, this fixed it for me. Thank you!!

Comment: i did not mean to say in brackets, i mean in ""

Answer (score 1):

The form itself is probably being submitted by default process due to no quotes around the `onsubmit` value

Try modifying to

```
onSubmit="return false"
```

I would also prevent the default of the button click

```
$("#SubmitRegister").on("click", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     // other code the same
```

Also you shouldn't redirect until you make the ajax request

Comment: oh my i didnt realize it was not in brackets, this fixed it for me, I did not bother with prevent default as I tried before and did not work. Thank you!!

Comment: If there is a space in an html attribute value and no quotes....anything after the space is ignored

Comment: yeah i know I just did not pick up that it was not in ""